# How to search a character by decimal code in emacs?

Tags: search, vim, emacs, character

In Vim I can search the character `”` (decimal 8221) and replace it by `"` using:

```
:%s/\%d8221/"/g
```

How can I do this in emacs? I've tried this using evil mode but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the hex number that corresponds to that decimal number.  You can easily find it by typing `M-:` and entering the number.  It shows this in the mode line:

```
8221 (#o20035, #x201d, ?”)
```

Note the part after `#x`, in this case `201d`.

Then, type `M-%` to start a search-and-replace.  For the search string, type `C-x 8 RET`, and then the hex number. That will insert the corresponding Unicode character into the search string.  Then, hit RET to move on to the replacement string, entering `"` there.

Comment: The decimal can be used by preceding the number with #10r.